# Silverlight 5: ComToolKit error

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I'm coding on a requirement that a tablet needs to store photos and metadata together in a LOCAL database because our dock workers are without network connection in some areas of our docks we need to be able to store the photos and additional data to a sqlexpress db on their tablets.

I'm trying to access my local sqlexpress database from silverlight using ComToolKit 
and I'm running into a runtime error on this line of code:

```
using (var connection = new ComToolkit.Data.AdoConnection(connectionString))
```

the error:

> System.TypeLoadException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=Could not load type 'System.Windows.Interop.ComAutomationFactory' from assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

StackTrace:

```
   at ComToolkit.Data.AdoConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at SilverlightApplication1.MainPage.PopPrograms()
   at SilverlightApplication1.MainPage..ctor()
   at SilverlightApplication1.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

I changed my using statement from:

```
using System.Windows.Interop;
```

changed to:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation;
```

and I'm still having issues. Anybody familiar with Silverlight and ComToolKit here?

referencing link http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/117/posts/14645/access-a-local-sql-compact-database-from-silverlight-4.aspx

Comment: Its not impossible to access a local sql express database from silverlight I just need the right person to look at my problem

Comment: Are you running in the browser? I may be mistaken, but I was under the impression that you can only use COM when running Silverlight in OOB or Out of Browser mode.

Comment: I've got the OOB settings set I think

Comment: Again I'm uncertain on this point, but I think you have to actually be running it outside of the browser. Just turning on OOB settings isn't enough. Basically this means your program needs both an in-browser, limited functionality and a OOB, full functionality mode. (That annoyance is why I gave up and went back to WPF+ClickOnce.)

Comment: Beware, ComToolkit simply does not work with Silverlight 5 and no one has offered up a new version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without ComToolkit, if you are willing to tolerate a little bit of `dynamic` and somewhat lousy performance.

Since you are using COM, you will need to run with Elevated Permissions of course.

The sample code below runs the query in a background worker. This is necessary because the query can be slow, and this avoids freezing the UI while query is still running.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FetchData();
    }

    private void FetchData()
    {
        List<Site> sites = new List<Site>();

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, e2) =>
        {
            dynamic conn = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
            conn.ConnectionString =
                @"Provider=sqloledb;
              Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
              Initial Catalog=SamDb;
              Integrated Security=SSPI";
            conn.Open();

            dynamic recordSet = conn.Execute("SELECT SiteId, SiteName FROM Sites");
            recordSet.MoveNext();
            while (!recordSet.EOF)
            {

                string siteName = (string)recordSet.Fields.Item(1).Value;
                short siteId = (short)recordSet.Fields.Item(0).Value;

                sites.Add(new Site(SiteId: siteId, SiteName: siteName));

                recordSet.MoveNext();
            }
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e2) =>
        {
            this.ListSites.ItemsSource = sites;
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: the namespace name 'Component' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel'

Comment: My first attempt at creating this app was done using window form application, the webcam capture dll only captured images from devices without dual webcams, then I found silverlight and the capture image process seemed to work fine for silverlight v.5

Comment: It sounds like your project structure is broken. If you want to save time, just start a new project and then add back your files. System.ComponentModel is in the System.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\System.dll

Answer (score -1):

IIRC Silverlight is supposed to run in a fairly high security sandbox, and has very restricted access to services (such as COM and databases) on the client machine.

Most Silverlight project templates in Visual Studio also create a server side project which the Silverlight client can talk to; db access would occur on the server. I'm fairly sure that classes such as DataSet cannot be used in a Silverlight client, so I think you're going in the wrong direction here...

Comment: So the ComToolKit I downloaded to work with Silverlight is bogus?